# What is the purpose of the shrouds surrounding these rocket engines?

Tags: rockets, engines, engine-design, liquid-fuel

While researching the purpose of some rocket engine components, I came across several images of perforated shrouds surrounding the combustion chambers of rocket engines.
I was highly curious about what purpose they serve, but was unable to find clear evidence.

The LR87-AJ-11, a late version of the LR-87, which was designed and build by Aerojet-General features such shrouds, for example, as seen [here](https://engineering.purdue.edu/%7Epropulsi/propulsion/rockets/liquids/lr87aj11.html) and [here](https://www.flickr.com/photos/jacksnell707/6848518571) (all rights reserved to Jack Snell).

It should be noted that earlier variants of the LR-87 do not feature such a shroud as far as I am able to tell.

Another engine which would have featured such a shroud is the AJ-1200, which was an engine proposed for a pressure-fed space shuttle booster which was never built.
The proposed schematics of the AJ-1200 can be found [here](http://www.alternatewars.com/BBOW/Space_Engines/AJ-1200_Engine.pdf), and the shroud can be spotted on
pg. 5, 9 and 11.

The only thing these engines appear to have in common is that they were both designed (or updated) by the Aerojet-General Corp. in the late 60s or early 70s (1968 - 1972).

Perhaps someone of the designers from back then is aware of the function of the shrouds?
Or does someone have a clue as to what it could be?

Comment: I think the shroud should bear a part of the thrust force to reduce the strain of the combustion chamber.

Comment: @Uwe agreed, and with holes cut out for weight reduction.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the AJ-1200 document, very interesting.

Comment: @ Uwe and @Organic Marble ... The LR87-AJ-11  shroud is corrugated as well as perforated, making it a poor design for carrying thrust loads. If anything, corrugations provide a bellows effect to prevent it from picking up axial loads.

Comment: @Woody are you talking about the cylinder with oval slots cut in it above where the nozzle flares out? Because that's what we are talking about.

Comment: @OrganicMarble... Oops. My mistake. I was looking at the bellows below the slotted cylinder. What is the function of the bellows? Heat shield?

Comment: @Woody There is no bellows. These are the tubes to cool the nozzle wall.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are structural supports for the combustion chamber.

I didn't find a specific reference for those engines, but the Space Shuttle Main Engine (SSME) has a similar support, although it isn't perforated. On the SSME it's called the  "throat ring".

[image]

> The chamber includes a liner, jacket, **throat ring**, coolant inlet manifold, and coolant outlet manifold.
> The liner outer surface has 430 vertical milled slots that are closed out by electrodeposited nickel.
> The jacket halves are placed around the liner and welded. The coolant manifolds are welded to the
> jacket and the liner. **The throat ring is welded to the jacket to add strength to the chamber.**

Presumably the cutout holes are for weight reduction, this is common in aerospace structures.

References -

- [SSME Pocket Data Book](https://ia800704.us.archive.org/13/items/PocketDataRIRD87142SpaceShuttleMainEngine/Pocket_Data_RI-RD87-142_Space_Shuttle_Main_Engine.pdf) (image)
- [SSME Orientation](http://large.stanford.edu/courses/2011/ph240/nguyen1/docs/SSME_PRESENTATION.pdf) (quote, emphasis mine)

Comment: I am curious about the contents of the volume under the throat ring, if it isn't ventilated. Do they draw a vacuum? Flush it with something? Leave in whatever welding gas was used (if any)? Let in air?
I would have assumed they put a vent hole in, so that the pressure differential to the outside doesn't fluctuate during cool down and ascent.

Comment: @Rikki-Tikki-Tavi Interesting, and I don't know the answer. I took this picture of an SSME main combustion chamber in a museum...it doesn't look to have any vents. https://i.imgur.com/F7t7Ga0.jpg

Comment: @OrganicMarble Very interresting. Thank you very much for your answer! Perhaps the volume under the throat ring is connected to the accoustic cavities somehow?

Comment: @Darkcoucou There is a decent cross-section of the acoustic cavities here https://space.stackexchange.com/a/28142/6944 and while there is some flow through them, from this, I can't confirm a connection.

Comment: @OrganicMarble For various reasons, I think this was probably welded by electron beam and it therefore contains a vacuum, if there is no vent. I could also see it being filled with helium.